# Error when use Audio.Sound.pauseAsync() in expo-av

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

This is my code

```
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [playbackObject, setPlaybackObject] = useState(null as any);
  const [playbackStatus, setPlaybackStatus] = useState(null as any);

  const handleAudioPlayPause = async () => {
   try {
    if (playbackObject !== null && playbackStatus === null) {
      const status = await playbackObject.loadAsync(
        { uri: audioUri },
        { shouldPlay: true }
      );
      setIsPlaying(true);
      return setPlaybackStatus(status);
    }

    // // It will pause our audio
    if (playbackStatus.isPlaying) {          
      const status = await playbackObject.pauseAsync();
      setIsPlaying(false);
      return setPlaybackStatus(status);
    }

    // It will resume our audio
    if (!playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      const status = await playbackObject.playAsync();
      setIsPlaying(true);
      return setPlaybackStatus(status);
    }
 } catch (error) {
   console.log('error in play/pause ', error);
 }
};
```

the playAsync works fine, and playbackStatus.isPlaying change to true, but when pauseAsync() is executed it throws the following error:

```
 [Error: Encountered an error while setting status!]
```

I was looking in the documentation and in different forums without a solution yet, I even used the same example and it gives me the same error

Comment: Any update on this? Facing same issue! Why is everything in react native so buggy